# Exceptions in subject-verb agreement

Tags: grammar

Why this is the first and the third question are correct but not the second question?

1. Slow and steady wins the race.
2. Mary and Susan love eating.
3. The team are working well together.

Answer (score 0):

1. In this popular idiom, "slow and steady" is being treated as a collective, single virtue—namely, patience. The subjects aren't really "slow" and "steady"; rather, the idiom is taken to mean the following:

> Slow and steady [progress] wins the race.

2. Here, the verb is conjugated in the plural simply because of the compound subject "Mary and Susan."
3. Here, I would personally prefer to say:

> The members of the team are working well together.

Technically, "team" is singular, so it doesn't make sense to use a verb conjugated in the plural. However, some people do use plural verbs with these types of singular nouns when referring to the constituents of the group (doesn't mean they're right!).

It would also not make sense to say:

> The team is working well together. (Okay. The team... and what else... are working well together?)

Comment: Omg....thnks a lot....but i don't get the meaning of last one tho..

Comment: How should I know whether two nouns share the same idea or not?..like what abt these sentence.                                             
 1. horse and carriage is or are....

Comment: "Horse and carriage" referring to the mode of transportation (by means of a "horse and carriage") would be singular (e.g., "The horse and carriage is an old-fashioned means of transportation.") If you are literally referring to a horse and a carriage as two separate things, then you'd use "are": "The horse and carriage are compatible."